# Unable to update default list forms on a Sharepoint 2007 list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I have created some custom forms for a Sharepoint 2007 list using Sharepoint Designer 2007.  When I attempt to "install" these by opening the list properties dialog box in SPD, it appears to accept the change.  I select the appropriate content type, browse to the form file and then click Apply.  The new form appears in the dialog, but when I close the dialog and re-open it, the original form has been reinstated.  No errors are thrown.  I'm a site collection administrator so I think I have adequate rights.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this before in 2007 and sometimes it just didn't "stick". The process I found that worked more consistantly was to make sure the new form was not open in the designer when going through the dialog options to set the new NewItem form.